# Sum of digits in base $b$ the $n^{th}$ row of Pascal's Triangle

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, decimal-expansion

[Number of digits in row of Pascal's triangle is $O\left(n^2\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905576/number-of-digits-in-row-of-pascals-triangle-is-o-leftn2-right)

Out of curiosity, continuing off of the linked question, I present the following question:

What is the asymptotic growth of the sum of all the digits in the $n^{\text{th}}$ row of Pascal's Triangle, when all the binomial coefficients are written in base $b$?

It can be assumed that $b$ is a positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume that most of the digits are random, so if there are $m$ digits in the sum, the sum of digits is about $\frac {b-1}2m$.  The leading digits may be biased low, but there are only $n$ leading digits in row $n$, so the non-leading digits will dominate.  The sum of digits is then $\frac {b-1}2 n^2  \in O( n^2)$

Comment: If we assumed each digit was random, then wouldn't the sum be the average digit multiplied by the number of digits?

Comment: In that case, why isn't the sum of digits asymptotic to $n^2$, just like the number of digits?

Comment: I had confused myself into taking the number of digits in $n^2$.  Fixed